# Apache proxyPassReverse and Websockets

Tags: apache, websocket, mojolicious, proxypass

I've been working on a Perl Mojolicious project that uses websockets. I'm wanting to launch it on a shared server running apache and use proxyPass and proxyPassReverse to make the url prettier for my Mojolicious code running with Hypnotoad.

I have it set up as follows.

Apache url:

```
mydomain.com
```

Hypnotoad url:

```
mydomain.com:8080
```

With the following apache entry I can reverse proxy the Hypnotoad server to

```
project.mydomain.com
```

apache.conf entry

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName project.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/project
  <Directory /var/www/project/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://mydomain.com:8080/ keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.com:8080/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-HTTPS "0"
</VirtualHost>
```

However my websocket requests give a 404 error when I use:

```
ws://project.mydomain.com/get-data
```

and a 302 error when I use:

```
ws://mydomain.com:8080/get-data
```

I guess this wouldn't be a problem is the websocket didn't check for authentication, but they use Mojolicious routes to check that you can post via the websocket.

From what I can see Apache doesn't support reverse proxying websockets. In apache/httpd conf files.

Has anyone found a usable solution to this using Apache that is stable for a production environment?

Answer (score 16):

In March [a patch was committed to the Apache trunk](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201303.mbox/%3C54924C1C-42BF-410E-AFAE-194BE378C69E@jaguNET.com%3E) by Jim Jagielski which allows websockets to be proxied correctly. The patch adds a new submodule called proxy_wstunnel which [allows mod_proxy to work with the "ws" and "wss" protocols](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201303.mbox/%3CDA1B7825-90BC-41C5-9F42-66C4E154D6E2@jaguNET.com%3E).

The module is not yet in any official Apache releases (as of June 8th 2013), so you will need to compile it yourself. [Voyageur's blog](http://blog.cafarelli.fr/post/2013/04/26/Backporting-Apache-support-for-websockets-reverse-proxy-%28aka-getting-GateOne-to-work-behind-Apache%29) describes the process for Apache 2.2, but it should be easier for Apache 2.4

Answer (score 15):

Apache httpd 2.4.6 includes proxying websocket requests.

Comment: This would be more suited to a comment rather than an answer. Once you [have enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), please consider moving this to a comment on the question.

Comment: @SameerSingh I think this is _exactly_ the answer to the question, by the committer of the patch.