# Meteor on httpd (Apache/2.4.6 CentOS) proxy and WebSockets

Tags: apache, meteor, proxy, websocket

I can't workout how to get WebSockets to work when I deploy my meteor app online. I keep getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://website.com/sockjs/***/********/websocket' failed: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I think this is due to the fact that apache sits in front of my meteor app. I know `Apache 2.4` had a bug to make `ws://` working, but I think this should be resolved by `modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so`, which I have enabled (of course I have enabled also `modules/mod_proxy.so`)

Here's my config. I'm running `Meteor 1.2.1` as a systemd service (`/etc/systemd/system/meteor.service`) like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=meteor nodejs daemon
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/root/www/main.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=meteor
Environment=ROOT_URL=http://website.com
Environment=PORT=3000
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the output of `httpd -v`

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug 28 2015 22:11:18
```

And this is the relevant part in my vhost config (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) for `website.com`:

```
<VirtualHost my.ser.ver.ip:8080>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    <Proxy *>
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've already tried to add the `RewriteCond` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371105/1435476) but no success...

Any idea? I'm also having issue getting `oauth` to work with the `accounts-facebook` package and I guess the problem is for the same reason? As in, there is something wrong in my proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the mystery. Of course it was my bad: I forgot all about Varnish.

I had Varnish set on port 80 forwarding the request to Apache, which was in turn proxying the request to node.js. I resolved by removing apache and thus configuring Varnish to serve straight to node.js for that specific domain.

This is what I did:

1. Implemented [this  default.vcl](http://www.servermom.org/install-varnish-4-lamp-centos-7/1972/) in `/etc/varnish/`
2. Removed `import directors` and all the content inside `sub vcl_init {}` (as I only have a single server)
3. Replaced `set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend();` in `sub vcl_recv {}` with:

---

```
if (req.http.Host ~ "^(www\.)?website.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = nodejs;
} else {
    set req.backend_hint = apache;
}
```

4. Created the two backends like so:

---

```
backend apache {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .max_connections = 300;
    .probe = {
        .request =
            "HEAD / HTTP/1.1"
            "Host: localhost"
            "Connection: close";
        .interval = 5s;
        .timeout = 1s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .connect_timeout = 5s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 2s;
}

backend nodejs {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3000";
    .connect_timeout = 1s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 2s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}
```