# Firefox Keep-Alive, Upgrade ruining websocket through apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, firefox, websocket

I have the following apache2 configuration that is working for chrome and internet explorer:

```
Listen 80

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
        #ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://IP:8585/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://IP:8585/

        ProxyPass /call  ws://IP:8585/call
        ProxyPassReverse /call  ws://IP:8585/call

        ProxyPass /call/  ws://IP:8585/call/
        ProxyPassReverse /call/  ws://IP:8585/call/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8585%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is it does not work through firefox.

The only difference I have seen is that firefox sends `Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade` instead of simply `Upgrade`.

Do I need to change my Rewriterule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to add a condition to your rewrite rules.  The below configuration will work as it checks for Connection values of `Upgrade` *or* `keep-alive, Upgrade`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^keep-alive,\ Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8585%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but it doesn't seem to. Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure you change the websocket URL and port to your target.  I'm using this configuration with Firefox without issue

Comment: What worked for me was dropping the `^` on `^Upgrade$`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371105/1274820