# How to setup meteor project in subdirectory at host?

Tags: node.js, meteor, centos, centos7, centos6

trying to deploy a meteor application to centos 6 google cloud server, I followed this [post](http://debojyotisdba.blogspot.com/2015/12/install-and-deploy-meteor-app-on-centos.html) after two days of setting up this server and compiling the project I stocked with the last step where I need to configure the app URL so what I did for now

1) create a sub directory at `"/var/www/html/myproject"` in centos 6 google cloud server

2) install nodejs v8.12.0 throw nvm

3) install mongodb 4.0.4

4) installing meteor 1.7.0.5 because my project is version 1.7.0.5

5) bundling my meteor project using `"meteor build myproject"`

6) uploading the genrated `myproject.tar.gz` to the server using FTP client to `"/var/www/html/myproject"`

7) unzip the `myproject.tar.gz` cd to `/var/www/html/myproject/bundle/programs/server` exucut `npm install`everything is installed and ok

8) setting the PORT `export PORT=3084`

9) setting the MONGO_URL `export 
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myprojectdb`

10) setting the ROOT_URL `export ROOT_URL=http://domain/myproject/` **is that right to do so like `http://domain/myproject/` or `http://domain/`is that correct thing to do?**

11) i installed forever `npm -g install forever`

12) `forever start /var/www/html/myproject/bundle/main.js` and it's run without errors

and here where I got stocked how can I access my project how can I configure the app url to access it like http://mydomin/myproject I tried like the psot says in step 7 "Step 7: configure a reverse proxy in your apache configuration"

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/yourapp_domain.conf
```

then

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myproject
  ProxyRequests off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://serverip:3084/myproject
    ProxyPassReverse http://serverip:3084/myproject
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but I couldn't access the website throw `http://serverip:3084/myproject` I'm new with server configurations, and I couldn't find any good resources online doing what I'm trying to do please any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recommended nginx configuration for meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003689/recommended-nginx-configuration-for-meteor)

Comment: I think you are really just looking for the right way to configure your nginx proxy. I've marked this as a duplicate of a good question+answer for that. BTW, what *is* your domain? I see "domain", "mydomin" and "serverip". So where is it?

Comment: hi @ChristianFritz I'm using apache server do I need nginx? for meteor, is nginx better with meteor rather than apache? thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002744/how-to-set-up-an-apache-proxy-for-meteor-sockjs-and-websocket