# Websocket is connecting on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: apache, firefox, websocket, proxypass

I am working on a apache proxy to WebSockets and the connection works great on Chrome and Safari Mobile but Firefox returns a 200 Ok Status and disconnects.

The server in question is a Centos 7 server running Apache and the websocket is provided by NodeJS.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName alpha.example.com
    ServerAlias www.alpha.example.com
    DocumentRoot public_html/
    ErrorLog logs/error.log

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLProxyEngine On

    Include cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile chain.pem

    ProxyRequests Off

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

    ProxyPass /ws http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /ws http://127.0.0.1:8080

</VirtualHost>
```

Chrome connects to the server and I can send events both ways. Firefox attempts a connection but then closes immediately with a 200 Ok Status but logs `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://alpha.example.com/.` Firefox however can load Proxy requests like `https://alpha.example.com/ws`

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is due to the different `Connection` header in the GET call.

for Chrome is:

```
Connection: Upgrade
```

while for Firefox is

```
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
```

So, you need to change the RewriteCond for `Connection` to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
```

Also please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371105/2186777